# Getting "illegal_argument_exception" error while loading dataset in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, load, bulkinsert

I am getting started with elastic search, I am trying to load the JSON dataset using the _bulk method. But I am getting the below error.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason" : "Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_NUMBER]"
    } ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "Malformed action/metadata line [1], expected START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT but found [VALUE_NUMBER]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Seems like some issue with my JSON file, I validated the JSON and it seems to be okay.

Here is my sample file.

```
{
"id": 3,
"customer_number": "",
"last_name": "anon",
"first_name": "zin",
"email": "anon@xyz.com",
"phone_number": "409-860-9006 x109",
"registered_at": "2007-05-02T16:27:50.74-05:00",
"last_visit_at": "2014-07-18T11:06:15-05:00",
"adcode": "",
"adcode_id": 0,
"affiliate_id": null,
"customer_type_id": 0,
"is_no_tax_customer": true,
"comments": "a",
"store_id": 5,
"source": "",
"search_string": "",
"no_account": false,
"sales_person": "SSB",
"alternate_phone_number": "800-936-9006 x109",
"is_affiliate_customer": false,
"updated_at": "2014-06-30T18:34:11.043-05:00",
"created_at": "2007-05-02T16:27:50.74-05:00",
"username": "",
"is_contact_information_only": false,
"tax_exemption_number": "",
"company": "anon",
"source_group": "",
"store_payment_methods_enabled": [0],
}
```

And the statement used to post the data is mentioned below.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary "@account_sample.json"
```

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last comma from the file:

```
{
"id": 3,
"customer_number": "",
"last_name": "anon",
"first_name": "zin",
"email": "anon@xyz.com",
"phone_number": "409-860-9006 x109",
"registered_at": "2007-05-02T16:27:50.74-05:00",
"last_visit_at": "2014-07-18T11:06:15-05:00",
"adcode": "",
"adcode_id": 0,
"affiliate_id": null,
"customer_type_id": 0,
"is_no_tax_customer": true,
"comments": "a",
"store_id": 5,
"source": "",
"search_string": "",
"no_account": false,
"sales_person": "SSB",
"alternate_phone_number": "800-936-9006 x109",
"is_affiliate_customer": false,
"updated_at": "2014-06-30T18:34:11.043-05:00",
"created_at": "2007-05-02T16:27:50.74-05:00",
"username": "",
"is_contact_information_only": false,
"tax_exemption_number": "",
"company": "anon",
"source_group": "",
"store_payment_methods_enabled": [0]
}
```

your document was not valid json.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by the error reason, it is expecting `START_OBJECT or END_OBJECT`

Also please note that your JSON is incorrect due to the presence of an extra comma at the end of the last field `"store_payment_methods_enabled": [0],`.
Another point which you should consider is you cannot have endline characters within the JSON, the entire JSON should be one line.

Even though you might have a valid JSON, if you don't provide the kind of operation you wish to perform (START_OBJECT in this case), you will get this error.

You might have to change the contents of your input file `account_sample.json` to below:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "someindex", "_id" : "1" } }
{"id": 3,"customer_number": "","last_name": "anon","first_name": "zin","email": "anon@xyz.com","phone_number": "409-860-9006 x109","registered_at": "2007-05-02T16:27:50.74-05:00","last_visit_at": "2014-07-18T11:06:15-05:00","adcode": "","adcode_id": 0,"affiliate_id": null,"customer_type_id": 0,"is_no_tax_customer": true,"comments": "a","store_id": 5,"source": "","search_string": "","no_account": false,"sales_person": "SSB","alternate_phone_number": "800-936-9006 x109","is_affiliate_customer": false,"updated_at": "2014-06-30T18:34:11.043-05:00","created_at": "2007-05-02T16:27:50.74-05:00","username": "","is_contact_information_only": false,"tax_exemption_number": "","company": "anon","source_group": "","store_payment_methods_enabled": [0]}
```

Please refer to [Elastic Search Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) to know more about how these APIs work.